# What is the difference between んだけど、 ですけど 、 けれども

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning and Correct use of all three words. I often saw japanese People ending there sentences in these words ? Explain

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: The meaning is generally the same with all three, with the difference coming from how you choose to structure the sentence around the use of です/だ.

For 〜んだけど and 〜ですけど, both of these have the same meaning with the only difference between them being their level of formality with です being more formal. They are typically used to express exception, clarification, or disagreement. An example might be:

Informal:

> まだ時間【じかん】があるんだけど、本当【ほんとう】に間【ま】に合【あ】う？
>
> There's still time, but will I really make it?

Formal:

> 今日【きょう】はいい天気【てんき】ですけど、風邪【かぜ】をひいたので出【で】かけられません。
>
> The weather today is good, but since I caught a cold I can't go out.

For disagreement, it's worth mentioning that it's not uncommon to simply end the phrase without follow-up, for example:

> 今月【こんげつ】はちょっと金欠【きんけつ】ですけど...
>
> I'm running a bit low on money this month...

As for けれども, this is a more formal version of simply saying けど. The meaning is the same as before, with the only difference being that it is not prefaced with です/だ. For example:

> 美味【おい】しそうなレストランに行【い】きましたけれども、あまり美味【おい】しくなかったです。
>
> I went to a restaurant that looked tasty, but it wasn't very good.

There is also だけれども/だけども, which can carry the meaning "though", "much as", or "while". Outside of this it is very similar to what is said above.

Answer (score -1):

It is additionally made more confusing by the fact that some people introduce themselves with this at the end of their sentence, like:

> クリスですけど。

It's more prevalent in phone conversations, and is used to soften your introduction. Maybe a bit like "sorry to bother you" or "it's ___ calling". An example I found online is:

> A: もしもし、Aです。
> B: Aさん、Bですけど。